# Why am I getting multipleDefine Error on my web Xpages

Tags: dojo, xpages

Why do I get multipleDefine errors for dojo and query on my web pages?

I am using Bootstrap and KendoUI

I *think* the problem is because in my theme I include jQuery from KendoUI

```
<resource>
    <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
    <href>/.ibmxspres/domino/KendoUI/js/jquery.min.js</href>
</resource>

<resource>
    <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
    <href>/.ibmxspres/domino/KendoUI/js/kendo.all.min.js</href>
</resource>
```

and these maybe colliding with the css being loaded from 
Xpages Bootstrap. If so, what can I do?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using Kendo UI also. I have a theme that extends the Bootstrap3 theme and this gives me JQuery so I don't need a resource tag for JQuery in my theme.

If extending Bootstrap3 theme is not going to work for you have a look at the new "advanced" theme in version 17 of the extension library called "Bootstrap3_blank". This will allow you more flexibility on the css that is included.

Documentation on the Bootstrap3_blank theme can be found here: https://wiki.openntf.org/display/EXTLIB/How+to+use+the+Bootstrap3_blank.theme+in+XPages

Comment: That was it. I just commented out the line in my theme that got jQuery from kendo. Now all is good. Thank you.