# Upgrade fontawesome from 4.7 to 5.13 in my XPages app, some questions

Tags: xpages, font-awesome

In my XPages application I want to upgrade the fontawesome version from 4.7 (current) to 5.13 (latest?)

So I added the resources and added to my themes design element:

```
<resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/css/solid.css</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/js/solid.js</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/js/v4-shims.js</href>
    </resource>
```

I have not updated the font-references and when I reload a page oddly all current icons are displayed somehow "Italic", should that be the case?

I have also defined some css pseudo-elements e.g.:

```
label.required:after {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: "FontAwesome";
    content: "\f069";
    color: #d9534f;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

but here the asterix icon i no longer displayed. How should i handle this?

Finally (for this post) I get 2 errors in the console:

GET http://dev.acme.org/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/dijit/dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.woff net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

http://dev.acme.org/xsp/.ibmxspres/.extlib/responsive/dijit/dbootstrap-0.1.1/theme/dbootstrap/font/fontawesome-webfont.ttf net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

What have I forgotten?

P.s. If I choose to use a kit instead of hosting the files myself the problem with the pseudo classes and the italic display do not occur. But I still have the 2 missing files errors

Comment: Where have you stored the web fonts?  There does not appear to be an NSF file in the URL.

Comment: I have stored them the webfonts folder, similar structure as in the download. the solid.css file refers to that folder e.g. src: url("../webfonts/fa-solid-900.eot");

Answer (score 0):

Update your css into:

label.required:after {
    margin-left: 5px;
    font-family: "Font Awesome 5 Free";
    content: "\f069";
    color: #d9534f;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 14px;
}

Might solve your asterix issue?

Answer (score 0):

What if you would load both versions?

```
<resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.css</href>
    </resource>

    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/css/solid.css</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>text/css</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/css/v4-shims.css</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/js/solid.js</href>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <content-type>application/x-javascript</content-type>
        <href>font-awesome/5.13.0/js/v4-shims.js</href>
    </resource>
```

fontawesome 5 does not use the fontawesome-webfont so it must be a reference in the theme you are using (bootstrap-flat?) if so try the bootstrap_blank option https://wiki.openntf.org/display/EXTLIB/How+to+use+the+Bootstrap3_blank.theme+in+XPages

it is previously discussed in this topic [Why am I getting multipleDefine Error on my web Xpages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38509270/why-am-i-getting-multipledefine-error-on-my-web-xpages) but no real examples are given. good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Try load the style sheet via the headtag example:

```
    <xp:headTag tagName="link">
        <xp:this.attributes>
            <xp:parameter
                name="rel"
                value="stylesheet">
            </xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter
                name="type"
                value="text/css">
            </xp:parameter>
            <xp:parameter
                name="href"
                value="font-awesome-5.13.0/css/all.css">
            </xp:parameter>
        </xp:this.attributes>
    </xp:headTag>
```